# Change all href links in Dreamweaver using RegEx

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I am trying to use Dreamweaver Find and Replace regex feature, to find and replace all href links that start with "/url-to-page.html" to "./url-to-page.html"? But not sure how to do so. Can someone please help with any example on how to do so (Regex required to do so) ? Thanks

Comment: Please provide more information, specifically, a sample of the html to be replaced and a piece that shouldn't be replaced.

Comment: @PedroLobito <a href="/testpage.html">link text</a> to <a href="./testpage.html">link text</a>

Comment: Ok, thanks, please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Find :** `<a href="\/(.*?)">`
**Replace:** `<a href="./$1">`

Make sure you check **Use regular expression** at the bottom

Comment: Thanks Pedro but this regex will just change any occurrence of /*page.html in html code despite if it is a link (href or not), is there anyway I can make sure that only the links changed are those href links?

Comment: I get an error on the find Regex as follows:  / Unescaped delimiter

Comment: Try escaping the slash `<a href="\/(.*?)">` . I don't have dreamweaver to test and I also don't know the posix it uses.

Comment: I am sorry but the Replace regex is not working, I tried escaping the slash but still not working....any thoughts what I might be missing here?

Comment: Please take a look at https://www.adobe.com/devnet/archive/dreamweaver/articles/regular_expressions_pt2.html to see some examples that may help you..

Comment: The issue is not in using the find and replace window, as I've used it with other regex and it works without any problem. The problem is that the 2nd regex <a href="./$1"> is not adding the . before the / make sense?

Comment: I makes sense, but I've no idea why it's happening, it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

I would say if you just had to do this for a single string:

Find: .*/url-to-page.html
Replace: ./url-to-page.html

Answer (score 0):

`href="(.*)"` to search and find it in all your tags

`attributeName=(.*)` to pin your regex search